# Can you set a VS Code terminal profile to automatically run commands upon opening?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, settings, vscode-remote-ssh

I find myself in a position where it would be useful to open a VS Code terminal profile and have it automatically run certain commands.

The specific case is I want to set up a profile where it automatically ssh's into another machine.  I am doing this because I do my dev work on one machine (machine_A), but the actual running of the code occurs on a second machine (machine_B).  Is it possible to make a profile that automatically runs

```
ssh {user_name}@{machine_name}
```

upon opening the profile?

Machine_A and machine_B are both remote and being accessed through RemoteSSH.  (And no I cannot do the dev work on the same machine I run the code.)

I am currently defining a custom profile in the workspace settings file (`{workspace}/.vscode/settings.json`) as suggested by [the VS Code docs on terminal profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles).  My current attempt is:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "ssh_session": {
            "path": "ssh",
            "args": \["{user_name}@{machine_name}"\]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd instead try to start a specific shell, and then use shell-specific mechanisms to run those commands. Your shell might have a mechanism to take commands from the commandline (Ex. Bash `-c`), or to take commands from a startup/profile file from a file at a specific, fixed location(s) or a customizable location specified in the commandline. If from a file at a fixed location such as a Bash profile / bashrc file, you can scope any general VS Code-specific workflow stuff to go inside a control flow block conditioned upon environment variables like `TERM_PROGRAM` being set to `vscode`. If you want to run commands on the remote side of the SSH connection, consult your SSH client's documentation. OpenSSH, for example, has a command parameter for specifying a command to run on the remote side.